# Named Pipe is only reading and not writing

Tags: c, named-pipes

I have an InPipe meant for reading in binary data and an OutPipe meant for writing back the binary data that passes through my firewall.

```
/// The input named pipe, "ToFirewall"
static FILE* InPipe = NULL;


/// The output named pipe, "FromFirewall"
static FILE* OutPipe = NULL;
```

I open both pipes in a separate function.

```
static bool OpenPipes(void)
{
    //ToFirewall
    InPipe = fopen("ToFirewall", "rb");
    if(InPipe == NULL)
    {
       perror("ERROR, failed to open pipe ToFirewall:");
       return false;
    }

   OutPipe = fopen("FromFirewall", "wb");
   if(OutPipe == NULL)
   {
      perror("ERROR, failed to open pipe FromFirewall:");

           return false;
       }

   return true;
}
```

For some reason as I read in data, it will skip over the write and doesn't bother to check if it passed through my firewall or not. I looked online and I read solutions about flushing, but it did not help.

```
static void* FilterThread(void* args) {
    OpenPipes();

    unsigned char* buffer = malloc(1500);

    int ret = fread(buffer, 1, 1500, InPipe);
    if(ret){
        fclose(InPipe);
    }


    //Check is FilterPacket will allow the packet through the firewall
    if(FilterPacket(buffer, args)) {
        fwrite(buffer, 1, 60, OutPipe);
        fflush(OutPipe);
    }

//        fflush(OutPipe);
    fclose(OutPipe);

    return NULL;
}
```

Here is my output

```
RCVR: opened file output.bin
SNDR: Waiting 200ms between packets
SNDR: Number of packets: 18
SNDR: Starting packet 0
SNDR: Starting packet 1
SNDR: Starting packet 2
SNDR: Starting packet 3
SNDR: Starting packet 4
SNDR: Starting packet 5
SNDR: Starting packet 6
SNDR: Starting packet 7
SNDR: Starting packet 8
SNDR: Starting packet 9
SNDR: Starting packet 10
SNDR: Starting packet 11
SNDR: Starting packet 12
SNDR: Starting packet 13
SNDR: Starting packet 14
SNDR: Starting packet 15
SNDR: Starting packet 16
SNDR: Starting packet 17
SNDR: Finished, wrote 18 packets to the pipe
```

And here you can see what the expected output should actually look like

```
> RCVR: opened file output.bin
SNDR: Waiting 200ms between packets
SNDR: Number of packets: 18
SNDR: Starting packet 0
SNDR: Starting packet 1
RCVR: 129.21.37.11 -> 74.125.21.103
SNDR: Starting packet 2
RCVR: 74.125.21.103 -> 129.21.37.11
SNDR: Starting packet 3
SNDR: Starting packet 4
RCVR: 129.21.37.11 -> 74.125.21.103
SNDR: Starting packet 5
SNDR: Starting packet 6
RCVR: 74.125.21.103 -> 129.21.37.11
SNDR: Starting packet 7
RCVR: 129.21.37.28 -> 74.125.21.103
SNDR: Starting packet 8
SNDR: Starting packet 9
RCVR: 129.21.37.11 -> 74.125.21.103
SNDR: Starting packet 10
RCVR: 74.125.21.103 -> 129.21.37.28
SNDR: Starting packet 11
SNDR: Starting packet 12
RCVR: 74.125.21.103 -> 129.21.37.11
SNDR: Starting packet 13
RCVR: 129.21.37.28 -> 74.125.21.103
SNDR: Starting packet 14
SNDR: Starting packet 15
SNDR: Starting packet 16
RCVR: 129.21.37.11 -> 74.125.21.103
SNDR: Starting packet 17
RCVR: 74.125.21.103 -> 129.21.37.28
SNDR: Finished, wrote 18 packets to the pipe
FwSim, Commanding firewall to Exit
RCVR: 74.125.21.103 -> 129.21.37.11
Exiting
```

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Where in the program do you print the output? Have you check what `fread` (and also `fwrite`) actually returns?

Comment: Oh, and you know that pipes are *streaming*, meaning it might not give you all the data you ask for in one read call, you might have to read in a loop.

Comment: What's on the other end of the pipes?

Comment: The InPipe is a tream of IP packets that are being read in. Where OutPipe is where I n.eed to write the IP packets that passed through my filter. I've tried to read in a loop, then write it out 60 bytes at a time. But my problem is that it doesn't seem to call the write functions and just reads in all of the packets only.

Answer (score 0):

The read reads up to 1500 bytes of data, but you were only writing 60 bytes. You might want to fix this:

```
fwrite(buffer, 1, ret, OutPipe);
```

And the write will only happen with the filter checked returns true, so to help debug, I suggest add a log when the filter returns false:

```
if(FilterPacket(buffer, args)) {
    fwrite(buffer, 1, ret, OutPipe);
    fflush(OutPipe);
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "FilterPacket returned false for packet %s\n", buffer);
}
```

Also, `buffer` is not released when the function returns, this will cause memory leak, add this to the end of the function:

```
free(buffer);
```